# difference between coward and pusillanimous

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms

I just discovered the word pusillanimous, and I wonder if there's actually a difference between pusillanimous and coward/cowardice?

Considering the etymology of both words, both seem qualify someone being unable to act, making both words very close synonyms.

Is there actually a difference, maybe based on context?

Comment: What does the dictionary show?

Answer (score 3):

The two words have similar meanings, but different implications.  Perhaps most significant is that *cowardly* tends to imply something about the subject's actions, while *pusillanimous* bears more on their personality and behavior.

A pusillanimous person would tend to not take a position in a political discussion, eg, while a cowardly person might denounce an autocrat in private but would be loath to denounce the autocrat to his face.

Comment: What exactly is the difference here between actions (which define cowardice) and behaviour (which defines pusillanimity)?

Comment: @jsw29 - Another way to look at it is that the pusillanimous person has no convictions, while the cowardly person  lacks the courage of his convictions.

Answer (score 1):

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms*, first edition (1942) addresses *cowardly* and *pusillanimous* in an entry that also includes the allied terms *poltroon*, *craven*, *dastardly*, and *recreant*:

> **Cowardly, pusillanimous, poltroon, craven, dastardly, recreant** agree in meaning excessively timid or timorous. **Cowardly**, the most general term, implies a weak or ignoble, **pusillanimous** a mean-spirited and contemptible, lack of courage; as, "He...plac'd behind With purpose to relieve and follow them, *Cowardly* fled, not having struck one stroke" (*Shak[espeare]*); "*Cowardly* dogs! ye will not aid me then?" (*Shelley*); "I lived in a continual, indefinite pining fear; tremulous, *pusillanimous*, apprehensive of I knew not what (*Carlyle*); "having no materialized  class above it, it {American vulgarity} is not obsequious and *pusillanimous*" (*Brownell*).

Interestingly, *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984), the successor to the first edition of *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms*, drops all coverage of *cowardly*, *pusillanimous*, *craven*, *dastardly*, and the rest. The omission is all the more inexplicable in view of the fact that *Merriam-Webster's Ninth Collegiate Dictionary* (1983) includes the following usage note at the end of its entry for *cowardly*:

> COWARDLY, PUSILLANIMOUS, CRAVEN, DASTARDLY mean having or showing a lack of courage. COWARDLY implies a weak or ignoble lack of courage; PUSILLANIMOUS suggests a contemptible lack of courage; ...

In its usage note, the *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003)—the most recent in the series—adds examples of *cowardly* ("a *cowardly* failure to stand up for principle") and *pusillanimous* ("the *pusillanimous* fear of a future full of possibility") but otherwise retains the same description of each that appears in the *Ninth Collegiate*. So either the lexicographers at Merriam-Webster consider the difference between "a weak or ignoble lack of courage" and "a contemptible lack of courage" to be fundamental and obvious or they haven't bothered to revisit the distinction since they set it down back in 1942, even as the *Dictionary of Synonyms* branch of the organization has withdrawn from the discussion altogether.

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968) offers this commentary on *cowardly* and *pusillanimous*, which it discusses along with *craven*:

> **cowardly craven pusillanimous** These words mean lacking courage to a degree that arouses disapproval and disgust. *Cowardly* is the most common word of the three, and is applied opprobriously to persons who are unwilling or unable to prevent their fear or timidity from influencing their actions unduly; it can also refer to the actions themselves: In frontier days, shooting a man in the back was considered *cowardly*; too *cowardly* to stand up and fight.

> *Craven* and *pusillanimous* are formal words encountered mainly in writing. ... *Pusillanimous* differs from the other terms in in pointing more strongly to temperamental timidity than to fear as the basis of the resulting action or inaction. *Pusillanimous* represents a contemptible moral squeamishness rather than a physical cowardliness, although it is quite possible for the same person to be both *pusillanimous* and *cowardly*. What chiefly distinguishes the *pusillanimous* person, however, is his unwillingness to press for his rights: His *pusillanimous* reaction was to sigh and say, "Well, it really won't do to raise a fuss."

These various attempts to distinguish between *cowardly* and *pusillanimous* touch upon several possible points of difference:

> **1.** *Cowardly* is a more general term and is therefore applicable to a broader range of situations.

> **2.** *Pusillanimous* is a more literary term and is therefore less likely to be encountered on the streets of Laredo.

> **3.** There is some sense that *cowardly* may apply to situations where the act (or failure to act) is understandable, though it fails to meet even a minimum standard of appropriate conduct under the circumstances; that is, in some cases, it may apply to an uncharacteristic but explicable failure of nerve and thus indicate a temporary shortcoming. *Pusillanimous*, on the other hand, seems to go to a habit of mind—a fundamental, ever-present lack of bravery that leads to cowardly behavior even when meeting an acceptable standard of conduct wouldn't require unusual fortitude or high-mindedness; this would explain the association (by both Merriam-Webster and Hayakawa) of *contemptible* with *pusillanimous* but not (or not necessarily) with *cowardly*.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the terms *coward* and *pusillanimous*  is one of usage, not in meaning. The overwhelming majority of native speakers will use "coward/cowardly/cowardice" exclusively in *speech*, and have only read or heard of "pusillanimous" while studying for the SAT or GRE test.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pusillanimous) says
early 15c., from Late Latin *pusillanimis* "having little courage" (used in Church Latin to translate Greek *oligopsychos* "small-souled"), from Latin *pusillis* "very weak, little" (diminutive of *pullus* "young animal," from PIE root *pau- "few, little") + *animus* "spirit, courage".

Which literally means the “small courage of a soul”.

Fans of the American TV show "The Sopranos" will remember a mob gangster whose nickname was [Big Pussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Sopranos_characters#Salvatore_%22Big_Pussy%22_Bonpensiero), which could be highly offensive (slang for vagina) or insulting, “[You must do this, **you big pussy!**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pussy)” (whether the cowardly meaning of  *pussy* is the abbreviation of pusillanimous is debatable but it cannot be excluded) instead, according to Wikipedia, the character's name refers to the feline variety.

Comment: The origins of *pusillanimity* in the Latin translation of *oligopsūchia*  and *mikropsūchia* point in the direction of its having a different meaning from *cowardice*, which is the standard translation for *deilia*. In Aristotle's classification of virtues and vices *mikropsūchia* and *deilia* are distinct vices, and chances are that this reflected how Greeks at the time generally understood these terms. The hypothesis that *pussy* is based on *pusillanimity* cannot be excluded, but its defence would need to explain how the single *s* turned into double *s*.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is indeed a considerable overlap between the two, they are not quite the same. *Pusillanimous* can be used as a rough synonym for *timid*, while *cowardly* cannot.

Cowardice always involves fear of some relatively definite adverse consequences. A soldier may be cowardly in a battle because he fears being killed by the enemy. A cowardly employee never contradicts his boss, because he fears that the boss may retaliate in some way.

A pusillanimous person, on the other hand, need not have any such reason for behaving in pusillanimous ways. A pusillanimous person will not contradict his boss even he is quite confident that the boss won't retaliate. It's just in his nature that he doesn't contradict people; he is not assertive enough for that, and he doesn't like drawing attention to himself.